# Laravel 4: create comment for a specific post

Tags: php, nested, laravel, laravel-4, blogs

I am making a simple blog with posts and comments.  The resource Comments is a nested resource of Posts. This is the route:

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

Until now i manage all the Post crud and seeing all the comments belonging to a post.

But i don't know how can i create a comment for a post.

In my `CommentsController` i have the RESTful method create:

```
class CommentsController extends BaseController {

  protected $comment;


public function __construct(Comment $comment)
{
     $this->comment = $comment;
 }

public function create($post_id)
{
    return View::make('comments.create');
}
```

And this is my View create for Comments:

```
@extends('master')

@section('blog')

<div class="span12 well">
  <h4>Make a Comment</h4>
</div>
<div class="span12 well">

  {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'comments.store')) }}

  {{ Form::close() }}
</div>
@stop
```

But it doesn't work. I get this error:

> Unable to generate a URL for the named route "comments.store" as such
>   route does not exist.

I try also to `make('route' => 'posts.comments.store'))` and i get this error:

> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts") to generate a URL for
>   route "posts.comments.store".

Can someone help me please?

EDIT:
THis is my Comment Model:

```
class Comment extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $guarded = array();

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Post');
    }
}
```

and this is my Post Model:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array(
        'title' => 'required',
        'body' => 'required');

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Comment');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having

```
Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController'); 
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'CommentsController');
```

You have 2 store route options:

```
posts.store
```

and

```
posts.comments.store
```

**But not**

```
comments.store
```

**EDIT:**

If you take a look at your routes (execute `php artisan routes`) you'll see that the route to posts.comments.store is:

```
GET /posts/{posts}/comments/create
```

So, for this route to work you need to pass the Post id when creating an url to that particular route. This is how you do it in `Form::open()`:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('posts.comments.store', $post_id))) }}
```

And you also need to tweak your controller to make it pass the post Id to your view:

```
public function create($post_id)
{
    return View::make('comments.create')->with('post_id', $post_id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
The both options don't works.
If i make posts.store i get the validation error because is trying to fill up the fields of the post form (while this is the comment form). 
Using posts.comments.store i get this error:

Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts") to generate a URL for route "posts.comments.store".

Comment: Thanks for reply Antonio!
I did it but it does not work.
I'm still getting: 
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts") to generate a URL for route "posts.comments.store".

I don't know, probably is somewhere else the problem?
I edit the question to write them the two models.

The problem seems to be when calling posts.comments.store inside the Create comment view.
Without that, the page open properly.

I have the same problem if i try to edit or show the single comment, i get the same error.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to add an array declaration to the route. Just fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now i resolved the problem!

Can i just ask the last question?
In the store method, after saving the new comment, i want to redirect to the route comments.index, with all the comments of that specified post.

And so i made:
return Redirect::route('posts.comments.index');
But i get this error:
Some mandatory parameters are missing ("posts") to generate a URL for route "posts.comments.index".

What i have to do in this case?

Comment: Again, since your route is based on a particular Post, you must pass on the post_id to Redirect: `Redirect::route('posts.comments.index', $post_id);`

Comment: I get this error: Parameter "comments" for route "posts.comments.show" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

Comment: That's a problem in another route in your source code: posts.comments.show. You're probably missing to send the comment_id to it too.

Comment: This is my method show:

 public function show($post_id, $comment_id)
 {
  $comment = $this->comment->find($comment_id);
  return View::make('comments.show', compact('comment'))->with('post_id', $post_id);
 }

Comment: You're passing the whole comment record to it and it just needs the comment_id. `compact('comment_id')`

Comment: Still does not work. I am having a lot of troubles with nested resource because i do not know how to deal with it.
Do you know perhaps where i can see an example of how to use it for example in a blog with post and comments crud?
How can i learn it?